# How do I use strtok to cut a string that varies in size?

Tags: c, string, strtok

So, i'm fairly new to C, and i get as input a string like this `a:name:number:number:number:number:name:name` and i'm using strtok to get all the names and numbers without the `":"`. The thing is, the size the string can vary and it can have up to more 2 names(always at the end) like: `a:name:number:number:number:number:name:name:name` or `a:name:number:number:number:number:name:name:name:name`.

Now, i'm using a struct and strcpy to get each name in the struct but because of the quantity of names changes in the end, i get Segmentation Faults when there are less than 4 names at the end, which is the maximum number of names(minimum is 1) and I think it's because i continue to do strtok after the end of the string.

Here's my code:

```
char *token;
structname a;
token = strtok(c,":"); //c is the input string
strcpy(a.name1,strtok(NULL,":"));
a.number1 = atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
a.number2 = atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
a.number3 = atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
a.number4 = atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
strcpy(a.name2,strtok(NULL,":"));
strcpy(a.name3,strtok(NULL,":"));
strcpy(a.name4,strtok(NULL,":"));
strcpy(a.name5,strtok(NULL,":"));
```

So, i'm guessing that the error occurs because it continues to do strtok even after the string is over in the cases where there are no 4 middle names? 
I want to know how i can, for example, in a case where there are 2 names at the end, just get `a.name4` and `a.name5` to `"\0"` or just dont get anything in those strings.
Thanks for time and help!

Comment: Why not `sscanf` ?

Comment: The question confuses me for giving the impression that you are unaware of arrays. Please explain why you use numbered variables (struct members) instead of an array.

Comment: I just tested on macos and strtok will not segfauls, it just keep returning null. What would happen is that you strcpy is segfaulting

Comment: test this on your platform: https://pastebin.com/xjW2bYtK

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/ryIPWLt_N here it segfaults,

Answer (score 1):

Typically, strtok is used in a loop. For example:

```
char *token = strtok(input_string, ".");
while(token != NULL) {
    //do code
    token = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

This way, the loop ends when the first failed parse happens. strtok should continue to return NULL after the end of the input string anytime you use it, so that shouldn't be causing the issue, but it might be.

The most likely issue in my opinion is with the way you use strtok in strcpy. The strcpy is probably failing because the source string is NULL. What I would do if you don't want to use the loop is

```
token = strtok(NULL, ":");
strcpy(a.name2, token);
```

This way, you ensure that it isn't a NULL pointer before trying to copy. strcpy works on an empty string (""), but it doesn't work on a NULL pointer.

The other thing you may want to check is that the destination strings (a.name2, etc) are allocated enough space. If not, this would also cause a seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

strotok() returns NULL if there is no more tokens. So you should check return value, for example:

```
if( (token = strtok(c,":")) != NULL ) 
    strcpy(a.name1,token);
else
   // token is NULL, there is no more tokens, end of string reached
   // you can return or do something else
```